# How can I draw a line with color and semi-transparent by wand

Tags: python, image, imagemagick, wand

I use the code like blow to draw a semi-transparent black frame on my picture, border width 5 pixels.

```py
from wand.color import Color
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display
from wand.drawing import Drawing

# ... init image

with (Drawing() as draw):
    draw.stroke_width = 5 
    draw.fill_color = Color('transparent')
    draw.stroke_color = Color('rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5)')
    draw.rectangle(left=frame_offset, top=frame_offset, 
        right=w-frame_offset, bottom=h-frame_offset)
```

But the `Color('rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5)')` gives a solid black border, not semi-transparent as expected.

I had tried some value of the alpha setting in color constructor without successful, and in document of `wand` there is no description about it. Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: I do not believe that Imagemagick can draw with transparency in the color. I think you have to draw lines to create a mask as well and then put the mask into the alpha channel of the image with the lines.

Comment: I believe the paint-color can have an alpha channel, but it's true you can't draw existing pixels-on-canvas transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `a` after `rgb` color definition. Just update the `Drawing.stroke_color` property to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)`.

```py
with Image(filename='logo:') as img:
    with Drawing() as ctx:
        ctx.fill_color = 'transparent'
        ctx.stroke_width = 5
        ctx.stroke_color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        ctx.rectangle(left=60, top=80, width=520, height=340)
        ctx(img)
    img.save(filename='output.png')
```

[image: output.png]

Comment: @emconville. Do you have maybe a suggestion to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74002947/distinction-about-txt-file-and-pdf-file