# distinction about txt file and pdf file

Tags: python, django, wand

I have a django application and a upload method. And A textarea where the content of the file will be returned. So if there is a text file uploaded. Then in the textarea the content of the textfile will be visible.

I try it now also with a image in a pdf file. And I try it with a console app. And that works. Tha text in the pdf file will be extracted.

But I try it now with the general upload method. And then I get this errror:

```
TypeError at /

image must be a wand.image.Image instance, not <UploadFile: UploadFile object (45)>

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     4.1.1
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

image must be a wand.image.Image instance, not <UploadFile: UploadFile object (45)>

Exception Location:     C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py, line 9310, in __init__
Raised during:  main.views.ReadingFile
Python Executable:  C:\Python310\python.exe
Python Version:     3.10.6
```

So this is the complete method:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import ProfileForm
from .models import UploadFile
from .textFromImages import TextFromImage
from wand.image import Image as wi
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from django.conf import settings
import io
import os


class ReadingFile(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
            "form": form
        })

    def post(self, request):
        submitted_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        content = ''

        if submitted_form.is_valid():
            uploadfile = UploadFile(image=request.FILES["upload_file"])

            name_of_file = str(request.FILES['upload_file'])
            uploadfile.save()

            with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                                   f"{uploadfile.image}"), 'r') as f:
                
                print("Now its type is ", type(name_of_file))

                # reading PDF file                
                if name_of_file.endswith('.pdf'):
                    pdfFile = wi(uploadfile, resolution=300)
                    text_factuur_verdi = []

                    image = pdfFile.convert('jpeg')
                    imageBlobs = []

                    for img in image.sequence:
                        imgPage = wi(image=img)
                        imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

                    for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
                        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
                        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
                        text_factuur_verdi.append(text)

                    return text_factuur_verdi                    
                # ENDING Reading pdf file
                
                else:
                    content = f.read()
                    print(content)               

            return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
                'form': ProfileForm(),
                "content": content
            })

            return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
                "form": submitted_form,
            })
```

My question: So what I have to change?

Thank you

This are the error lines:

```
 C:\Users\engel\Documents\NVWA\software\blockchainfruit\main\views.py, line 39, in post

                        pdfFile = wi(uploadfile, resolution=300)

     …

Local vars
C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py, line 9310, in __init__

                        raise TypeError('image must be a wand.image.Image '
```

even I I do a hardcoded path string:

```
 pdfFile = wi("C:\\Users\\engel\\Documents\\NVWA\\software\\blockchainfruit\\uploads\\images\\fixedPDF.pdf", resolution=300)
```

I get the same error:

```
TypeError at /

image must be a wand.image.Image instance, not 'C:\\Users\\engel\\Documents\\NVWA\\software\\blockchainfruit\\uploads\\images\\fixedPDF.pdf'
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 142, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\engel\Documents\NVWA\software\blockchainfruit\main\views.py", line 42, in post
    pdfFile = wi(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 9310, in __init__
    raise TypeError('image must be a wand.image.Image '

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: image must be a wand.image.Image instance, not 'C:\\Users\\engel\\Documents\\NVWA\\software\\blockchainfruit\\uploads\\images\\fixedPDF.pdf'
```

Somebody any idea how to tackle this?

I have it now like this:

```
 # reading PDF file
                if name_of_file.endswith('.pdf'):
                    pdfFile = wi(filename= uploadfile.image.path , resolution=300)
                    text_factuur_verdi = []

                    image = pdfFile.convert('jpeg')
                    imageBlobs = []

                    for img in image.sequence:
                        imgPage = wi(image=img)
                        imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

                    for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
                        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
                        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
                        text_factuur_verdi.append(text)

                    return text_factuur_verdi
                # ENDING Reading pdf file
```

And so this is the html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Create a Profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "main/styles/styles.css" %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form }}
      <button type="submit">Upload!</button>
  </form>   
  {% if content %}
      <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">{{content}}</textarea>
 {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have provided `UploadFile` instance instead of `wand.image.Image` instance.Can you specify the line in which error occured?

Comment: Oke, I just need the path of the uploadid file. But how to return the path of the uploaded file?

Comment: can you post the complete error page

Comment: What does this `wi` function do, is it created by you or you have installed some module as you also imported it as `from wand.image import Image as wi` what is this?

Comment: Yes, it is a module. I installed  from wand.image module: https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.10/

Comment: It should be either `wi(uploadfile.image, resolution=300)`  if it takes the name of image or `wi(uploadfile.image.path, resolution=300)` if it takes the path, try both the approaches but I think the first one should work as official wand docs says its to be the filename, refer [here](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.10/wand/image.html)

Comment: Your fieldname inside `UploadFile` model must be `image`. kindly tell me if any of the two works.

Comment: @SunderamDubey Yes, oke. I get the full paht with this:   pdfFile = wi(filename= uploadfile.image.path , resolution=300). But what do you mean with you second comment? Where I have to put image?

Comment: @SunderamDubey  But If I changed to image.path... then I get this error: AttributeError at /

'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @emcconville. Do you maybe have a suggestion?

Comment: But it is working in a console python app. But Now I do it in the Django framework. And I get this error.  The method is working. So there has to be a solution to let it work in the Django framework. Look at this youtube clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRUcMiXZt5Q is the same code. And it works. So why it doesn;t work in Django?

Comment: @SunderamDubey. ohhhhh my. It has to be without return statement!!!       content = text_factuur_verdi
        print(text_factuur_verdi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
   content = text_factuur_verdi
   print(text_factuur_verdi)
```